# Optimization Target must be a link

Tags: python, neural-network, chainer

I have an autoencoder model of 4 linear layers written using chainer.Chain. Running the optimizer.setup line in Trainer section give me the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-9-a2aabc58d467> in <module>()
      8 
      9 optimizer = optimizers.AdaDelta()
---> 10 optimizer.setup(sda)
     11 
     12 train_iter = iterators.SerialIterator(train_data,batchsize)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/chainer/optimizer.py in setup(self, 
link)
    415         """
    416         if not isinstance(link, link_module.Link):
--> 417             raise TypeError('optimization target must be a link')
    418         self.target = link
    419         self.t = 0

TypeError: optimization target must be a link
```

The link to class StackedAutoEncoder is as follows:
[StackAutoEncoder link](https://github.com/tochikuji/chainer-libDNN/blob/master/libdnn/autoencoder.py)

The link to class NNBase which is used to write class AutoEncoder is as follows:
[NNBase link](https://github.com/tochikuji/chainer-libDNN/blob/master/libdnn/nnbase.py)

```
model = chainer.Chain(
    enc1=L.Linear(1764, 200),
    enc2=L.Linear(200, 30),
    dec2=L.Linear(30, 200),
    dec1=L.Linear(200, 1764)
)


sda = StackedAutoEncoder(model, gpu=0)
sda.set_order(('enc1', 'enc2'), ('dec2', 'dec1'))
sda.set_optimizer(Opt.AdaDelta)
sda.set_encode(encode)
sda.set_decode(decode)

from chainer import iterators, training, optimizers
from chainer import Link, Chain, ChainList

optimizer = optimizers.AdaDelta()
optimizer.setup(sda)

train_iter = iterators.SerialIterator(train_data,batchsize)
valid_iter = iterators.SerialIterator(test_data,batchsize)

updater = training.StandardUpdater(train_iter,optimizer)
trainer = training.Trainer(updater,(epoch,"epoch"),out="result")

from chainer.training import extensions
trainer.extend(extensions.Evaluator(valid_iter, sda, device=gpu))
```

Chain is made of Links. I want to understand why the optimizer is not recognizing the sda which is StackedAutoencoder(model)?

Comment: Can you share the definition of StackedAutoEncoder class?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the links to StackedAutoEncoder and NNBase class...Also any additional pointers for the program is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StackedAutoencoder` inherits `NNBase` class, which inherits `object` class, so they are not `chainer.Chain` class.

You can refer official example for how to define your own network.
For example, [MNIST example](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/examples/mnist/train_mnist.py#L13-L26) defines MLP as follows:

```
class MLP(chainer.Chain):

    def __init__(self, n_units, n_out):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()
        with self.init_scope():
            # the size of the inputs to each layer will be inferred
            self.l1 = L.Linear(None, n_units)  # n_in -> n_units
            self.l2 = L.Linear(None, n_units)  # n_units -> n_units
            self.l3 = L.Linear(None, n_out)  # n_units -> n_out

    def forward(self, x):
        h1 = F.relu(self.l1(x))
        h2 = F.relu(self.l2(h1))
        return self.l3(h2)
```

Comment: So is there any way to make the optimizer recognize the optimization target as link even though StackedAutoEncoder class is not made up of links? Do I have to write StackedAutoEncoder class in ChainList  to make it work or is there a workaround?

Comment: You can pass only Link to optimizer's target. For example `optimizer.setup(sda.model)` if sda itself is not link but it holds `model` Link.